# Why is this basic assumption leads incorrect answer?

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

A thin cylindrical uniform metallic rod of Length 'L' and radius 'R' rotates with an angular velocity "omega" in a horizontal plane about a vertical axis passing through one of its end . The denisty and the Young's modulus of the material are "rho" and "Y" respectively
What is the elongation in length ?

My approach :
From non inertial frame ,
I assumed the stress to be the centrifugal force acting on the circular section ( of area πR² ) which caused the elongation .

By simple formula , it turns out that elongation is as :

[ Rho * (omega)² * L³ ] / ( Y )
Please tell why this is wrong.

( It is provided that above written elongation expression is incorrect )

Comment: I think your basic approach of using the centrifugal force should work. But, it would help if you could expand on what you mean by "By simple formula" (what formula?). One thing to pay attention to is that the centrifugal force depends on the distance from the axis of rotation, so the force acting on the rod is not uniform; correctly accounting for this is probably tricky enough that you can't just write down the right answer from a simple formula based on first principles.

Comment: By formula , I meant hookes law

Answer (score 0):

Your result is the elongation you would get if the whole of the rod's mass were concentrated in a small lump at the free end of the rod (the end furthest from the axis). The centripetal force needed by that lump would be transmitted by the rod, so the stress in the rod would be constant all along the rod – as I believe you have assumed.

You need to take account of the mass being distributed uniformly along the rod, so the stress due to transmission of centripetal force gets less and less as we go outwards along the rod from the axis-end. [At any point P along the rod, the force transmitted by the rod is the sum of the centripetal forces needed only by those portions of the rod beyond P.]

By considering the net force, d$F$ on each element of the rod, you'll find that the transmitted centripetal force decreases proportionally to $L^2-l^2$ in which $l$ is the distance along the rod from the axis end.

You now need to add up the extensions in each small 'slice', length $\text d l$, of rod. In other words another integration is called for, but not one that needs much mathematical expertise!

Incidentally, this answer is geared to an inertial frame of reference, but can be adapted to a the rod's rotating frame by changing a couple of words and a couple of signs!

Comment: Doesn't the centripetal force increase as we go away from the axis, F=mr$\omega^2$?

Comment: @Not_Einstein The centripetal force per unit length of rod increases, but I was talking about the *transmitted* centripetal force, that is the force needed for the whole of the rod beyond a certain point.

Comment: Ok , I think integrating the force over the rod is gonna help .

Comment: But If I'm not mistaken , then centripetal force at the extreme end is coming zero ! It means that the furthest point should not describe a circular motion , but clearly it does as it's moving along with the rod ?

Comment: The tension in the rod does indeed tend to zero as we go to the extreme end, simply because the mass that needs centripetal force tends to zero! The centripetal force *per unit mass* does not tend to zero!

Comment: Incidentally, when I carried out the calculations outlined in my answer, I obtained your original answer, but multiplied by a factor of $\frac 13$. I recommend that you carry out the calculations.